# Start background process in node (loopback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I am trying to start a process in loopback which "archives" a part of the database every 5 minutes.
Right now I am starting the archiver from a bootscript an schedule it every 5 minutes via setInterval:

```
// boot/start_archiver.js

setInterval(function(){
  console.log("Starting the Archiver");
  building_archiver.archiveBuildings();
  room_archiver.archiveRooms();
}, 300000);     // Archive every 5 minutes
```

I have a feeling that this is not the correct way of doing this, as it seems like the loopback API is unresponsive whenever the archiver runs.

How can I outsource the archiver call to a different process which runs separate from the API?
Can you point me in the right direction or help me find a good framework?

Comment: Since Node is single threaded, your code should never block for long. `archiveBuildings` is obviously not written in a non blocking way and  I'm guessing neither is `archiveRooms`.

Comment: You're right! Because it is so blocking, I was thinking about a child process or something similar. I doubt that I am able to rewrite the code in a non-blocking way :(

Comment: Then just run the archiver in a second node instance and connect the two through tcp. Or use a library like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads